# What is the meaning of generic container in HTML5?

Tags: html, element

The div element is known to be a generic container, what is exactly meant be the term generic container in HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a container with no special purpose.

It carries no semantics (unlike a `section` or a `main` or a `fieldset` etc).

> [of, applicable to, or referring to all the members of a genus, class, group, or kind; general.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/generic?s=t)

A div has nothing that every other container does not have (but the reverse is not true).

Comment: Would it not be wrong to say that <div> element carries no semantics, there is some meaning behind using it to have a block division.

Comment: @xingzao — "These things belong together" and "These things do not belong together" are, while meaningful, not *semantic*.

Comment: I think what @Quentin is trying to say is that we can put <div> anywhere that's why they are non-semantic, unlike <header> and <main>, as we have to put this semantic elements as per the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Generic containers are just containers that serve no special purpose. Mostly a style attribute is bounded to a generic container for specifying the rendering or using a CSS rule.

The only generic containers  are `<div>` and `<span>`.

Technically speaking, they could be used to organize webpages into multiple different "sections" defined with classes and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

## Semantic markup

"Good" HTML code is semantic.
In the current context it means, that you wrap the content of your webpage / webapp into containers which are designed to contain that specific piece of content.

For example, headers typically are semantically correctly coded into `<header>` tags, articles in `<article>`, so on and so forth.

## DIV as a Jolly Joker

Whenever you don't have a generic block level container at your disposal, you encapsulate the content you want to render in a `div`. It's usually the "last resort" tag you use when you run out of options.

## One more thing

As `<div>` is the jolly joker of block level elements (panels, GUI control containers, etc.) the `<span>` tag is the jully joker of inline elements

Answer (score -1):

Id say they typically just are simple holders that kinda define whats inside of them. They just hold stuff. Like a div typically is containing elements that go together. Like if you wanted to have a navigation bar, you can put all the elements that make it into a div and give that div an id or class of 'nav'. Keeps things nice and organized.